# Kibana visualization - Status page like Nagios

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, monitoring, kibana-4

is it possible to create a visualization in Kibana similar to Nagios's status page? Let's say to show a single value with red/green background based on a specific threshold, which I would set up in logstash by adding a field to the message...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this ticket](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/678) stands in your way.